# Push DependencyProperty back to ViewModel upon DataContext Change

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties

I dont know if I have some kind of design flaw in what I am writing but im a little stuck as to the approach I am currently trying to use.

I have a case in my ViewModel where I want to do clamping on certain values based on the *current state of the user-control*. For this to work, I need to bind to properties on that control and ensure that the ViewModel *always knows about its current state*.

In one instance, this works great. If a value changes on the control, the DependencyProperty of the View says, hey, ive changed. And the data is pushed to my ViewModel. Brilliant!

The problem arises when my ViewModel is switched out, and the View doesn't change. A great example of this would be the View's ActualWidth and ActualHeight. Upon a ViewModel switch (effectively removing the old one, and reinstantiating a new one). The DependencyPropertys will not change. Thus my new view model never recieves the data of the view.

This means that somehow my Control MUST know when its ViewModel changes. Right?

If this all makes sense, how do I go about "pushing" the new values to my view model. Even if they haven't changed?

Comment: Are you setting the DataContext on the view when the ViewModel changes? This should automatically update all bindings from the View to the ViewModel.

Comment: not exactly, all my viewmodels are in an observable collection, so the new one gets added to it & selected.

Comment: How are you binding your View to the 'active' ViewModel? Is the ViewModel a property in a master view model class?

Comment: Does the ViewModel property implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: This question needs some code to be answerable

Comment: *sniff sniff* You aren't having issues with a UserControl that has its own specialized ViewModel, are you?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes ofcourse!

Comment: @Will hmm not exactly!

Comment: The only work around I have so far. Is when I create and push my new viewmodel onto my observable collection, is to determine the type. If its the type which contains the "ViewWidth and ViewHeight" I forward it onto the next view model. Instead of assuming the control will push its dependency properties out.

This could be related to the fact its within an observable collection? Obviously they dont get updates. I wonder if I can force it somehow?